# how to prove det(B) = − det(A)

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Suppose that $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix and $A −(R_i ↔ R_j)→ B$ is obtained from $A$ by switching rows $R_i$ and $R_j$.

I am not really sure how to prove this.
Thanks!

Comment: Depends on which definition of determinant you're using, and what other properties of it you know.

Comment: @Minto Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3):

Switching for the rows can be obtained by left matrix multiplication by $S$ that is

$$B=SA $$

with $\det(S)=-1$. Then recall that

$\det(B)=\det(SA )=\det(S)\det(A)=-\det(A)$

Note that $S$ matrix is obtained by $I$ matrix switching the corresponding rows.

Answer (score 3):

You can prove this using the following row operations:

I just show it for $i=1$, $j=2$ to save time:

$$det\begin{pmatrix} r_1 \\ r_2 \\ \vdots \\r_n\end{pmatrix} = det\begin{pmatrix} r_1+r_2 \\ r_2 \\ \vdots \\r_n\end{pmatrix} = - det\begin{pmatrix} r_1+r_2 \\ -r_2 \\ \vdots \\r_n\end{pmatrix} = - det\begin{pmatrix} r_1+r_2 \\ r_1 \\ \vdots \\r_n\end{pmatrix} = - det\begin{pmatrix} r_2 \\ r_1 \\ \vdots \\r_n\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: That’s nice and from the basic properties for det(A).

Answer (score 0):

A determinant can be seen as [alternating multilinear form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilinear_form#Alternating_multilinear_forms).

So that property is a result of the alternation propery.
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{det}{det}
\det(\dotsc, a_i, \dotsc, a_j, \dotsc) =
-\det(\dotsc, a_j, \dotsc a_i, \dotsc)
$$

If you use the [Leibniz definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#n_%C3%97_n_matrices) of the determinant
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{sgn}{sgn}
\det A 
= \sum_{\pi \in S_n} \sgn(\pi) \prod_{i=1}^n a_{i\pi(i)}
$$
it is a property of the sign of the permutations.